# SQL Select, only one record per minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I have SQL select in PHP like this one:

```
$sql_GATE  = $conn->query("SELECT  * FROM GATE WHERE st='ff0000' and dataGate between '2018-06-27 00:00:0' and '2018-06-27 23:59:0' order by id desc ");
```

this code return to me aboute 120000 record like example:

```
1-ff0000-->2018-06-27 18:28:51<br>
2-ff0000-->2018-06-27 18:28:51<br>
3-ff0000-->2018-06-27 18:28:51<br>
13-ff0000-->2018-06-27 18:28:49 .......
```

How to write SQL request to return only one record per every 1 minutes
or 2 minutes? because in one second is aboute 3 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we have syntax and example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, colN, MAX(TimeAndDateColumn)
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE(TameAndDateColumn), HOUR(TimeAndDateColumn), Minute(TimeAndDateColumn)
```

Example:

```
SELECT id, latitute, longitude, speed, MAX(`time`)
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY DATE(`time`), HOUR(`time`), Minute(`time`)
```